# pypi server nginx docker-compose reverse proxy misconfigured

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, pypi

Goal:  Reverse-proxy to private pypi server with nginx (eventually with SSL, but I can't get it to work without yet.) in docker-compose

I can access pypi server on port 8080 when I launch it exclusively.
I can access nginx on port 80 when I launch it solo, or with pypi.

With the config below (both,) I can access `nginx` on port 80, but the `/pypi` path returns a 404.

When the nginx container is commented out, the pypi server responds on port 8080 as expected.

What's misconfigured?

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.3'
services:
# NGINX container
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:1.22.0-alpine
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d/pypi.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/pypi.conf
      - ./nginx/nginx_cache:/var/nginx/cache

# PYPI container
  pypi-server:
    image: pypiserver/pypiserver:latest
    container_name: pypi-server
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /home/ec2-user/auth
        target: /data/auth
      - type: volume
        source: pypi-server
        target: /data/packages
    command: run -P . -a .
    restart: always

volumes:
  pypi-server:
```

`pypi.conf`

```
server {
  location /pypi {
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port/pypi;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
  }
}
```

and from the `docker-compose logs` output, these two lines seem pertinent:

```
pypi-server    | Serving on http://0.0.0.0:8080
...
nginx          | 2023/06/12 00:29:02 [error] 31#31: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/pypi" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.90.0.5, server: localhost, request: "GET /pypi HTTP/1.1", host: "10.102.96.109"
```

Is it just ignoring the proxy config, or `pypi.conf` altogether? Is that due to some yml syntax, docker syntax, or permissions issues on the directories?

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED--and well, there were a few issues here.

First, `docker-compose` required mapping or exposing the `pypi` port `8080`, because `nginx` running in one container can't see `pypi` running in the other unless the ports are exposed.

Second, the tutorial I was following implicitly omitted `nginx/conf.d/default.conf` without explicitly stating that.  As a result, the settings in my `nginx/conf.d/pypi.conf` were ostensibly being overridden.

Third, there are some idiosyncrasies in the `nginx` configs, like trailing slashes in the correct places, that had an impact.

This now works with a single `nginx/conf.d/default.conf` that defines the reverse proxy in a way similar to the intended in the question.

**nginx/conf.d/default.conf**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;
 
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;
 
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
 
    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
 
    error_page  404              /404.html;
 
    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
 
    }
 
    location /pypi {
        proxy_pass        http://pypi-server:8080/;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
 
    location ~ ((?:simple|packages).*) {
        proxy_pass        http://pypi-server:8080/$1;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.3'
services:
# NGINX container
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    hostname: nginx
    image: nginx:1.22.0-alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/nginx_cache:/var/nginx/cache
 
# PYPI container
  pypi-server:
    image: pypiserver/pypiserver:latest
    expose:
      - "8080"
    container_name: pypi-server
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /home/ec2-user/auth
        target: /data/auth
      - type: volume
        source: pypi-server
        target: /data/packages
    command: run -P . -a .
    restart: always
 
volumes:
  pypi-server:
```

Some references:
[Setting up a Private Pypi Server with nginx and docker-compose](https://medium.com/geekculture/setting-a-private-pypi-server-with-nginx-acbb73c8516d)
[nginx beginners guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html)
[nginx pitfalls and common mistakes](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/)
[Pypi documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pypiserver/)

Answer (score 0):

I have further questions, this solution did work for me with regards to pypiserver working with NGINX, but it breaks my SVN repository, which I also have under NGINX.

It comes down to the fact that `location ~ ((?:simple|packages).*)` is intersecting requests to my SVN repository towards pulling and committing to things like `https://mysvnrepo.com/svnroot/mylibary/packages/mydev`.

So my question is there a way to just handle the pip installation to `/simple` and `/packages` within the `location /pypi`?

Comment: Have you tried adding a more explicit regex for the either the sv location, e.g., `location ~ (.+mylibrary/packages.+)`?

Comment: This is an ever growing svn repository. I do not know the exact number of the top my head, but there must be about 50 different `mylibrary` currently.